# Android TextView carousel animation

Tags: android, animation, carousel

I want to make 2d carousel animation in android but using textviews not images I saw this [code](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html) but he is using images not textviews, anyone can help me to do it, Thanks in advance